# How to merge two list of list in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

**Input**:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b=[[5,8,9],[2,7,10]]
c=[]

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
       if a[i][1]==b[j][0]:
           c[i].append(b[j][1])
           c[i].append(b[j][2])
print(c)
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

**Output** should be like this:

```
 c=[[1,2,3,7,10],[4,5,6,8,9]]
```

But when I run this code in python got this error, anyone can help me please, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where do the numbers 10 and 9 come from?

Comment: Please can you explain the logic why your desired list has `7, 10` and `8, 9` in the sub-lists instead of `5, 8` and `2, 7` which are part of list `b`

Comment: @moinuddin- Sorry, it was typo, I edit this already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve this using [`itertool.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) with *list comprehension* expression as:

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> b=[[5,8,9],[2,7,10]]

#               v  join the matched sub-lists
#               v                       v  your condition 
>>> [i + list(chain(*[j[1:] for j in b if i[1]==j[0]])) for i in a]
[[1, 2, 3, 7, 10], [4, 5, 6, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b=[[5,8,9],[2,7,10]]
c=[]


c.append(sorted(list(set(a[0] + b[1]))))
c.append(sorted(list(set(a[1] + b[0]))))
print(c)
```

But note I am sure there are other much more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b=[[5,8],[2,7]]
c=[]

for i in range(len(a)):
    x=a[i]+b[i]
    c.append(x)

print(c)
```

Here you go

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b=[[5,8,9],[2,7,10]]
c=[]
def list_concat_distinct(list1,list2):
    tmp=list1[:]
    tmp.extend([x for x in list2 if x not in list1 ])
    return tmp
c.append(list_concat_distinct(a[0],b[1]))
c.append(list_concat_distinct(a[1],b[0]))
print(c)
```

Hope this can help it.